# What permissions could make CreateFileA return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when the file clearly exists?

Tags: c++, boost

A little background here:

1) I'm using boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object as a message passing interface between two processes.

2) On the "server" side this creates a file.  On the "client" side this opens and reads the file. The file is created and read from C:\ProgramData\boost_interprocess.

3) The "client" side is launched from the "server" side using QProcess::startDetached()

4) All works fine when the application is installed on the local drive (C:)

5) When the application is installed on a network drive (N:) the "client" side reports ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when trying to read the file even though the "server" side clearly created the file.

```
Server side code (with logging statements):
 logFile << "  Attempting to create: " << shmfile.c_str() << "\n";
 m_handle = ipcdetail::create_new_file(shmfile.c_str(), mode, perm, true);
 logFile << "  Create finished.  File handle is: " << m_handle << "\n";
 if (boost::filesystem::exists(shmfile.c_str(), errorCode))
     logFile << "  Created file and it exists\n";
 else
     logFile << "  Attempted to create file and it does not exist.  Error code is: " << errorCode << "\n";

Client Side Code (with logging statements):
 if (boost::filesystem::exists(shmfile.c_str(), errorCode))
     logFile << "  DoOpen - File exists according to boost\n";
 else
     logFile << "  DoOpen - File doesn't exist.  Error code is: " << errorCode << "\n";
 logFile << "  Attempting to open: " << shmfile.c_str() << "\n";
 m_handle = ipcdetail::open_existing_file(shmfile.c_str(), mode, true, &logFile);
 logFile << "  Open finished.  File handle is: " << m_handle << "\n";
```

In the code above ipcdetail::create_new_file() and ipcdetail::open_existing_file() end up calling CreateFileA() at the lowest level.

An example log file which shows the error looks like:

From the server side:

- Attempting to create:
  C:\ProgramData/boost_interprocess/20151221093212.125599/{c94a1cac-d0e2-4f33-bc0e-3d26e6c19dd0}
- Create finished. File handle is: 0000000000000CF4
- Created file and
  it exists

From the client side:

- DoOpen File doesn't exist.  Error code is: system:2
- Attempting to open: C:\ProgramData/boost_interprocess/20151221093212.125599/{c94a1cac-d0e2-4f33-bc0e-3d26e6c19dd0}
- Open finished.  File handle is: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

As you can see from the code and the logs, the server side successfully creating the file and the boost::filesystem::exists() call shows that the file exists.  On the client side the very same boost::filesystem::exists() call is reporting that the file does not exist.  And eventually we wind down through ipcdetail::open_existing_file() to CreateFileA which reports the same issue.

Could this be as simple as a permissions issue?  If so, what permissions could cause a file to not even be found?

Comment: `end up calling CreateFileA() at the lowest level` You could try to call `CreateFileA` with the same arguments directly, and check `GetLastError()` upon failure. That might give you a more informative error code than simply `doesn't exist`.

Comment: This is likely because the process, when run from a network share, is running at lower permissions than when it is run locally.

Comment: If it's ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, it is definitely NOT permissions which is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I would suggest two causes: (i) your code or Boost.Interprocess is doing something after the failure which is corrupting GetLastError() which causes reporting the wrong code (ii) his use of CreateFileA could be problematic as the expansion of the exact same ASCII text could turn into different unicode depending on the currently prevailing codepage. This is why no library code should EVER use the ASCII Windows path functions, and you should upcall this as a bug with Interprocess.

Comment: could be informative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095188/85371